# @Startup annotation does not work

Tags: java, ejb, startup, postconstruct

I use the `@Startup` annotation to set entry point on the deploying process in EJB, but it does not work. See code example below:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class SchedulerManager {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerManager.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void atStartup() {
       System.out.println("stutrup!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

I'm using JBoss5.1.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Please, give me suggestion what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!
Artem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The @Startup annotation is part of ejb 3.1 / jee6 while jboss 5 only implements jee5. You would have to switch to jboss 6 to use it.

**Edit:** An alternative might be to implement the `contextInitialized` method of a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), which can be declared in web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>package.ListenerClassName</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks to advance. Maybe you know solution how I can call method on startup stage? only plz take into account I have not web part and only ejb project.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use JBoss 6. There are error for my project. And solution for this 6.0.1 version where would fix.

Comment: So far, the alternative is working for me. but then Jorn, can you help me at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570129/singleton-startup-postconstruct-doesnt-work-on-ejb3-1-and-glassfishv3-0-1