# @Singleton, @Startup, @PostConstruct doesn't work on EJB3.1 and Glassfishv3.0.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, ejb

I have a problem with this setup and I can't even view the logs.

This is my `@Singleton` `@Startup` EJB:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DependsOn("SchedulerEJB")
public class SchedulerStartUp {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerStartUp.class);

    @EJB
    SchedulerEJB schedEJB;  

    @PostConstruct
    public void atStartup() {
       log.info("startUp")
       System.out.println("startUp");

       schedEJB.cancelTimer("EBlastScheduler");
       schedEJB.createTimer("*/1", "*", "*");
    }
}
```

The `SchedulerEJB`:

```
 @Stateless
 public class SchedulerEJB {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;         

    public cancelTimer(String timerInfo){/*...*/}

    public createTimer(String sec, String min, String hour) {/*...*/}

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) {/*...*/}
 }
```

Maven pom:

```
 //Been Using Glassfishv3.0.1 and EJB3.1 with a dependency of:
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
     <version>6.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Can u debug it? Also, I had problems using commons logging, I ended up using slf4j `LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerStartUp.class)`

Comment: logging runs fine when the application is deployed, it only seems to happen when used at this context :(

Comment: Sadly no time for that :(, thinking of many things right now... help :((

Comment: Please change the '@EJB' assignee to the interface(the ones with '@Remote'/'@Local') not the EJB itself. and also please remove the '@DependsOn' when the dependency doesn't use @Singleton, that's all thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have invalid type of bean as an attribute of [@DependsOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/DependsOn.html). DependsOn is for expressing dependency between two Singleton session beans, not between Singleton and Stateless. You should change SchedulerEJB to be Singleton or remove dependency.

If you decide change SchedulerEJB to Singleton, then @DepensOn is also not needed, because (from EJB 3.1 specification):

> Note that if one Singleton merely needs to invoke another Singleton
>   from its PostConstruct method, no explicit ordering metadata is
>   required. In that case, the first Singleton would merely use an ejb
>   reference to invoke the target Singleton. There, the acquisition of
>   the ejb reference (either through injection or lookup) does not
>   necessarily imply the actual creation of the corresponding Singleton
>   bean instance.

Comment: But I need it to be @Stateless, any workaround? maybe I should remove '@DependsOn' totally? but will my '@EJB' work? :(

Comment: '@EJB' doesn't work, any way to initialize bean named 'SchedulerEJB' above?

Comment: I haven't have such a situation where I would call stateless bean from singleton, but I assume removing @DependsOn should work, assuming that there is not any hidden need in other parts of code why SchedulerEJB should be initialized before. Container should guarantee that there is instance available with your current code without any additions.

Comment: Thanks, its now clear! to other guyz reading this: "never import the wrong library just like what i did, i imported com.google.inject.Singleton instead of javax.ejb.Singleton" Thanks again!

Comment: I know it's an old question, On Jboss 7.x a I just used a @DependsOn to reference a stateless bean from a singleton bean: I don't think it's EJB3 compliant, but it works.    
Source this ticket: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=958217