# @Singleton @Startup depends on @Stateless EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the following setup:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DependsOn(value="DataSourceHandler")
public class TimerTask {

    @EJB(name = "DataSourceHandler")
    DataSourceHandler dataSourceHandler;
}

@Stateless(name = "DataSourceHandler")
public class DataSourceHandler {
    ... database operations
}
```

The timertask runs once every 30 minutes and performs database operations with the help of the DataSourceHandler EJB.

The problem here is that I'm unable to inject the EJB into the `Singleton` Timertask, because a singleton can only depend on other singletons. The solutions proposed in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8570129/2224996) don't work for me however:

- I can't make the `DataSourceHandler` a Singleton because it is also used in other parts of the application and not multithreading-save.
- I can't remove the Singleton from the `TimerTask` because it is required for the `@Startup` annotation

How can I inject a stateless into a singleton?

Comment: Why do you have a Scheduled Singleton class? Is there a reason for such design?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I need to regularily perform synchronisation and cleanup tasks on the database.

Comment: Is a timer or a startup singleton? Startup are for initialization, timer for scheduling, why togheter?

Comment: @maja I understand that, but why use `@Singleton` Bean?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I am using `@PostConstruct` to initialise the timer. If I don't have `@Startup`, the bean would never been created, would it?

Comment: A Timer Service an be a `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` session bean and you can use `@PostConstruct` in any EJB.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Thank you, I didn't know that. Using a `@Stateles` EJB for the timertask did the trick. Stateful does not work: `EJBConfigurationException: EJB 1.x, 2.0, and Stateful Session beans may not implement the javax.ejb.TimedObject interface`. If you can post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Are you using EJB 2 or EJB 3 in this instance?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi EJB 3.0

Comment: You don't need to implement `javax.ejb.TimedObject` interface from EJB 3.x. That interface was used in EJB 2.x and they have relaxed the requirements now.

Comment: I will post the answer as soon as I get to my desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **do no**t need a dependsOn annoatation here.
@dependson is used for the below case:

> Used to express an initialization dependency between singleton
>   components.

Since DataSourceHandler is an EJB, it will be instantiated by the container at the moment your singleton injects this EJB.